# reCaptcha preventing Input type number from respecting max attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, recaptcha

I have a form created with html5 that uses reCaptcha validation before allowing a submit.

The form has number type inputs that use the max and min attributes.

The attributes work in preventing the user from scrolling past the max or min values when using the arrows. If the users types the value in the form field any value can be entered. So far this is behaving as expected.
However, if the user enters a value greater than the max attribute value, validates the reCaptcha and then presses submit, the expected error pop-up does not appear, the form is submitted as is and it throws a 500 server-error (because the app does not expect the value submitted to it).

When the page was initially created and tested without the reCaptcha the input forms worked as expected.

This was tested on: Opera 38.0 on a window7 box and Firefox 47.0 on ubuntu 14.04.

Have I made an implementation error?

Here is my captcha validation:

```
<script>
    function get_action(form) {
      var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
      var isCaptchaValidated = false;
      if (response.length == 0) {
        isCaptchaValidated = false;
        alert('Please verify that your are human');
      }
      else {
        isCaptchaValidated = true;
      }

      if (isCaptchaValidated === true){
        document.getElementById("form").submit()
      }
    } 
</script>
```

What can be done to resolve this?

Comment: Where do you call get_action?

Comment: get_action is called from the submit button `<input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" value="Submit" onclick="get_action(form);">`

Comment: See the submit method [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit). Maybe you have to check it youself. See the [Data Form Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation)

Comment: I implemented the input:invalid pseudo class. This helps alert the user of an error but the problem persists. If the user submits invalid data the reCaptcha allows the data to sent to the server.

Comment: input:invalid gives you only a visible clue; it will not validate...